# I have installed Hadoop for one 'x' user on my Ubuntu machine. How can i access hadoop from other user 'Y'?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, sudo

When i try to run "Hadoop" in user "Y" i get error as - No such Command.Is there any way by which the same installation can be used which has been done for user "X" ?

Comment: Is `$HADOOP_HOME\bin` in the PATH?

Comment: yes it is there in .bashrc file of "X" User. `export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$JAVA_PATH/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin`.If i update the same to .bashrc file of "Y" user will it work?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user Y to have the same access as user x you will need all the Hadoop path variables set in user Y's .bashrc. Depending on how you installed Hadoop you will need to also add user Y to the hadoop user group that X is in. You may also need to create a user directory on HDFS. Also make sure ssh is running for user Y. You could use the namenode you formatted for user x, but you will need to make sure Y has access.

Once you have checked all of the above try typing

```
xx@yyyy$ bin/hadoop
```

You should see the documentation for the Hadoop command

Comment: Thanks this worked.Adding one more point changed the owner of directory as well.

Comment: It not wise to change ownership of a directory as it stands a good chance it may break something else. You should add your new user to that group that owns the Directory in question. Read up on Unix security

Comment: Actually i have deleted the old user and have now changed ownership of directories to new user.